# Issue with socket java

Tags: java, sockets

I have client and server in java. I can see welcome menu, but i can not go to the next steps. Ex. when i click 1 in client terminal, nothing happens. I think that server does not get informations from clinet. I hava no idea why i do not have communication between server and client. Can sameone help me?

Client

```
public class Client 
{ 
    private Socket socket            = null; 
    private DataInputStream  input   = null; 
    private PrintWriter out         = null; 
    private BufferedReader in        = null;
    private String line;
    private String response;

    public Client(String address, int port) 
    { 
        String line = "";
        this.response = "";
        try
        { 
            socket = new Socket(address, port); 
            System.out.println("Connected"); 

            input = new DataInputStream(System.in); 
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); 
        } 
        catch(UnknownHostException u) 
        { 
            System.out.println(u); 
        } 
        catch(IOException i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 

        while (!line.equals("2")) 
        { 
            try
            {   
                while ((response = in.readLine()) != null) {
                   System.out.println(response);     
                }

                line = input.readLine();

                out.println(line); 
            } 
            catch(IOException i) 
            { 
                System.out.println(i); 
            } 
        } 

        // close the connection 
        try
        { 
            input.close(); 
            out.close(); 
            socket.close(); 
        } 
        catch(IOException i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 5000); 
    } 
}
```

Server

```
public class Server {
    private Socket          socket   = null; 
    private ServerSocket    server   = null; 
    private BufferedReader in        = null;
    private PrintWriter out          = null; 
    private boolean isWelcomeMenu;
    private URL database;
    private String clientId;

    public Server(int port) 
    { 
        this.database       = this.getClass().getResource("database.txt");
        this.isWelcomeMenu  = true;
        this.clientId       = "";
        String line         = "";

        try
        { 
            server = new ServerSocket(port); 
            System.out.println("Serwer wystartował"); 

            System.out.println("Oczekiwanie na klienta ..."); 

            socket = server.accept(); 
            System.out.println("Zaakceptowano klienta"); 
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); 

            while (!line.equals("2")) 
            {    
                try
                { 
                    if (this.isWelcomeMenu)
                    {
                        welcomeMenu();
                    } else {
                        appMenu();
                    } 

                    line = in.readLine();

                    switch (line) {
                        case "1":
                                login();
                                break;
                        case "2":
                                close();
                                break;
                        case "3":
                                bankBalance();
                                break;
                        case "4":
                                payout();
                                break;
                        case "5":
                                payment();
                                break;   
                        case "6":
                                logout();
                                break;
                        default:
                                System.out.println("Nierozpoznana  komenda");

                    }  
                } 
                catch(IOException i) 
                { 
                    System.out.println(i); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        catch(IOException i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 


          } 
        } private void  welcomeMenu+() {
       out.println("1. menu");
       out.println("2. menu");
    }
    ....



       public static void main(String args[]) 
        { 
            Server server = new Server(5000); 
        }
```

Comment: What do you think `while ((response = in.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(response); }` does? Can it ever be `null`?

Comment: I have there 3 lines welcome response from server. I want to read all lines and after that send message to server and recive different response.

Comment: Then read 3 lines (loop 3 times), not "potentially infinite amount of lines (until `null`)".